# How to update object value the right way

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having issue updating my `object's` value.

I have an object that is structured like this:

```
const myObject =  {

      [_selectedDay] :
        {
        toDo:'workout',
        selected: true,
      }
  }
```

I have a button that adds my object and
When I `console.log` my object I get this:

```
//I expaned [0]
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] "object"
0: 
->2019-06-03: {toDo: "workout", selected: true}
1: {2019-06-04: {…}}
2: {2019-06-05: {…}}
3: {2019-06-06: {…}}
4: {2019-06-07: {…}}
```

My question: Is it possible to update `2019-06-03`'s `toDo` field from `workout` to study?

I tried this code but won't work.

```
 myObject[0].toDo = 'workout'
```

Comment: please post some runnable snippet. It's unclear what you're doing here.

Comment: From the looks of it. It should be `myObject[0][0].todo = 'workout'` as its an array in an array

Comment: Is it `toDo` or `todo` ? Javascript is case sensitive

Comment: @JonasHøgh it's toDo. I fixed it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So at first we should take a look at this:

```
(5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}] "object"
0: 
->2019-06-03: {toDo: "workout", selected: true}
1: {2019-06-04: {…}}
2: {2019-06-05: {…}}
3: {2019-06-06: {…}}
4: {2019-06-07: {…}}
```

`myObject[0].todo` is undefined because there is no `.todo` on `myObject[0]`. Furthermore ther is no `.todo` anywhere in your object. But theres a `.toDo` (D instead of d) on `myObject[0]['2019-06-03']`.

using `myObject[0]['2019-06-03'].toDo = 'study'` should work. :)

---

Off-topic: (to answer your comment):

This could be a solution if your data-structure should not be changed. Take a look at the comments inside the code:

```js
var myObject = [
  {'2019-06-04': {toDo: 'study', selected: true}},
  {'2019-06-05': {toDo: 'workout', selected: true}},
  {'2019-06-06': {toDo: 'party', selected: true}},
  {'2019-06-07': {toDo: 'work', selected: true}}
];

function catchbydate(key) {
  // loop through your array:
  for(var i = 0; i < myObject.length; i++) {
    // return if objectkey was found:
    if(myObject[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) return myObject[i];
  }
  // otherwise return null:
  return null;
}

console.log(catchbydate('2019-06-06'));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer it works great! I still have one question tho. Is it possible to `console.log `object values without using index number like this`[0] `. For example, I want to check if my object contains `2019-06-03` and then `console.log` Something like this `console.log(myObject['2019-06-03'])`

Comment: You're welcome. :) For this you have to build your own function and loop through your array of objects.

Comment: I see :) Again, thank you very much for the comments I really appreciate it! Btw, Do you mean like the code `AshishAgrahari` provided below? It seems like working to me. If that's not the case could you please share an example?

Comment: AshishAgraharis solution should be fine, if your data-structure could be changed. Otherwise take a look at my edited answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the first key:

```
var firstKey = Object.keys(myObject)[0];
myObject[firstKey].todo = 'workout'
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your comment on J Sadi's answer, somehow in your code, your "myObject" is getting converted to array of objects and hence you have to access it via index, like myObject[0]. If your structure remains correct like below, you can directly access (or console.log) your property like myObject['2019-06-03'].

```
myObject =  {
      2019-06-03 :
        {
        toDo:'workout',
        selected: true,
      },
      2019-06-04 :
        {
        toDo:'study',
        selected: true,
      }
  }
```

now you can do console.log(myObject['2019-06-03']).